# Selective Linq child include two levels deep

Tags: linq, entity-framework, include

I'm porting some sql stored procedure logic, which would return multiple tables in a dataset, to entity framework strongly typed objects, queried with linq.

Basically I need the data from tables A, B, and C, where C has a foreign key to B, and B has a foreign key to A. But I don't want every C with a FK to B, just the C's with a certain constraint X.

So basically, the stored proc basically said

```
TableA = select from A where A.AID = AIDPassedIn
TableB = select from B where B.AID = AIDPassedIn
TableC = select from TableB where TableB.XID = XIDPassedIn 
return new DataSet(TableA, TableB, TableC);
//yes this is gross and confusing, thus our current efforts
```

Entity framework *almost* makes this super easy like so

```
A.Include("B.C").Where(a => a.AID == AIDPassedIn)
```

My only problem is that this doesn't include constraint X on the C table. I've read a bunch of articles, but everything I've read suggests things I could add to the where clause, and that would filter what A objects I end up with. I should only end up with one A object though, regardless of the properties of it's children. What I want is The A with AIDPassedIn, and all it's child B's, and all the B's children C that match constraint X.

I feel like this is one of my worst phrased questions ever but I'm at a bit of a block. Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it along the lines of the following:

```
var AList = context.As.Where(a => a.AID == AIDPassedIn)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        A = a,
        Bs = a.Bs,
        Cs = a.Bs.Select(b => b.Cs.Where(c => c.XID == XIDPassedIn))
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => x.A)
    .ToList(); // or SingleOrDefault if AIDPassedIn is the PK
```

Entity Framework will put the object graph together automatically (even without using `Include`) as long as you don't disable change tracking.

Comment: Wow! I plugged in all my table names for A B and C and it worked like magic the first time! This was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much for the simple clear answer!